# How to recover faulty pam.d configuration?

Tags: security, pam

I am struggle to login after configured kerberos in `pam.d`. 
Eventhough , I tried with root user , it also  no use.  I know, I did something wrong on that but how can I restore the `pam.d` configuration? Is there any way to login my account?

How can I restore my pam configuration files?

Answer (score 1):

Try to boot with a live USB or CD/DVD with Ubuntu and edit the files that you need. 
[This post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1446724) will explain you how to do it.